# How can I move my longtable to the left?

Tags: longtable, fit

My table is sliding to the right and doesn't show entirely on the page. How can I make it fit? Also some rows are breaking.

Here's the code:

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}     
\small\sffamily\centering       
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-0.1pt}        

\begin{longtable}{@{} | p{6cm} | *{5}{c|} }
\caption{Species' description, habitats and migration}\\
\multicolumn{5}{c}{}\\

\endfirsthead

\hline
    Species & Family & Order & Habitat & Migration \\ 
    \hline
Pandion haliaetus & Accipitridae & Accipitriformes & water birds & migratory \\

    Anas platyrhynchos & Anatidae & Anseriformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

    Chauna torquata & Anhimidae & Anseriformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Anseranas semipalmata & Anseranatidae & Anseriformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

    Buceros rhinoceros & Bucerotidae & Bucerotiformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Bucorvus abyssinicus & Bucorvidae & Bucerotiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Rhinopomastus cyanomelas & Phoeniculidae & Bucerotiformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Upupa epops & Upupidae & Bucerotiformes & water birds & migratory \\

    Aegotheles bennettii & Aegothelidae & Caprimulgiformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Chaetura pelagica & Apodidae & Caprimulgiformes & land birds & migratory \\

    Chordeiles acutipennis & Caprimulgidae & Caprimulgiformes & intermidate regions & partial migratory \\

    Hemiprocne comata & Hemiprocnidae & Caprimulgiformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Nyctibius grandis & Nyctibiidae & Caprimulgiformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Podargus strigoides & Podargidae & Caprimulgiformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Calypte anna & Trochilidae & Caprimulgiformes & intermidate regions & partial migratory \\

    Chunga burmeisteri & Cariamidae & Cariamiformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Gymnogyps californianus & Cathartidae & Cathartiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Uria aalge & Alcidae & Charadriiformes & water birds & migratory \\

    Burhinus bistriatus & Burhinidae & Charadriiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Charadrius vociferus & Charadriidae & Charadriiformes & water birds & migratory \\

    Chionis minor & Chionidae & Charadriiformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

    Dromas ardeola & Dromadidae & Charadriiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Rhinoptilus africanus & Glareolidae & Charadriiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Ibidorhyncha struthersii & Ibidorhynchidae & Charadriiformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

    Jacana jacana & Jacanidae & Charadriiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Chroicocephalus maculipennis & Laridae & Charadriiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Pedionomus torquatus & Pedionomidae & Charadriiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Himantopus himantopus & Recurvirostridae & Charadriiformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

    Rostratula benghalensis & Rostratulidae & Charadriiformes & land birds & partial migratory \\

    Limosa lapponica & Scolopacidae & Charadriiformes & water birds & migratory \\

    Stercorarius parasiticus & Stercorariidae & Charadriiformes & water birds & migratory \\

    Thinocorus orbignyianus & Thinocoridae & Charadriiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Turnix velox & Turnicidae & Charadriiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Ciconia maguari & Ciconiidae & Ciconiiformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

    Colius striatus & Coliidae & Coliiformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Columbina picui & Columbidae & Columbiformes & water birds & migratory \\

    Halcyon senegalensis & Alcedinidae & Coraciiformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Brachypteracias leptosomus & Brachypteraciidae & Coraciiformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Eurystomus gularis & Coraciidae & Coraciiformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Merops nubicus & Meropidae & Coraciiformes & intermidate regions & partial migratory \\

    Baryphthengus martii & Momotidae & Coraciiformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Todus mexicanus & Todidae & Coraciiformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Centropus bengalensis & Cuculidae & Cuculiformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Eurypyga helias & Eurypygidae & Eurypygiformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Rhynochetos jubatus & Rhynochetidae & Eurypygiformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Falco peregrinus & Falconidae & Falconiformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

    Penelope pileata & Cracidae & Galliformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Alectura lathami & Megapodiidae & Galliformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Numida meleagris & Numididae & Galliformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Odontophorus gujanensis & Odontophoridae & Galliformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Tympanuchus cupido & Phasianidae & Galliformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Gavia stellata & Gaviidae & Gaviiformes & water birds & migratory \\

    Aramus guarauna & Aramidae & Gruiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Grus americana & Gruidae & Gruiformes & water birds & migratory \\

    Heliornis fulica & Heliornithidae & Gruiformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Atlantisia rogersi & Rallidae & Gruiformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Leptosomus discolor & Leptosomidae & Leptosomiformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Mesitornis unicolor & Mesitornithidae & Mesitornithiformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Corythaixoides concolor & Musophagidae & Musophagiformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Opisthocomus hoazin & Opisthocomidae & Opisthocomiformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Lophotis ruficrista & Otididae & Otidiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Acanthisitta chloris & Acanthisittidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Mohoua ochrocephala & Acanthizidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Aegithalos caudatus & Aegithalidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Alaudala cheleensis & Alaudidae & Passeriformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

    Artamus cinereus & Artamidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Atrichornis clamosus & Atrichornithidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Bombycilla garrulus & Bombycillidae & Passeriformes & land birds & migratory \\

    Callaeas wilsoni & Callaeatidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Edolisoma coerulescens & Campephagidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Cardinalis cardinalis & Cardinalidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Certhia familiaris & Certhiidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Chloropsis hardwickii & Chloropseidae & Passeriformes & land birds & migratory \\

    Cinclus mexicanus & Cinclidae & Passeriformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Cisticola juncidis & Cisticolidae & Passeriformes & water birds & migratory \\

    Climacteris rufus & Climacteridae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Cnemophilus loriae & Cnemophilidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Struthidea cinerea & Corcoracidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Corvus corone & Corvidae & Passeriformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Oxyruncus cristatus & Cotingidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Gymnorhina tibicen & Cracticidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Dasyornis broadbenti & Dasyornithidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Campylorhamphus procurvoides & Dendrocolaptidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Dicaeum eximium & Dicaeidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Dicrurus megarhynchus & Dicruridae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Dulus dominicus & Dulidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Sporophila hypoxantha & Emberizidae & Passeriformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

    Lonchura striata & Estrildidae & Passeriformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Ptilorrhoa leucosticta & Eupetidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Serilophus lunatus & Eurylaimidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Eulacestoma nigropectus & Falcunculidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Formicarius rufipectus & Formicariidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Serinus canaria & Fringillidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Furnarius figulus & Furnariidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Hirundo rustica & Hirundinidae & Passeriformes & water birds & migratory \\

    Molothrus ater & Icteridae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & migratory \\

    Irena cyanogastra & Irenidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Lanius ludovicianus & Laniidae & Passeriformes & water birds & migratory \\

    Machaerirhynchus nigripectus & Machaerirhynchidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Dryoscopus gambensis & Malaconotidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Malurus elegans & Maluridae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Melanocharis versteri & Melanocharitidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Notiomystis cincta & Meliphagidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Menura novaehollandiae & Menuridae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Toxostoma redivivum & Mimidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Myiagra hebetior & Monarchidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Motacilla alba & Motacillidae & Passeriformes & water birds & migratory \\

    Erithacus rubecula & Muscicapidae & Passeriformes & land birds & migratory \\

    Leptocoma aspasia & Nectariniidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Daphoenositta chrysoptera & Neosittidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Oriolus oriolus & Oriolidae & Passeriformes & land birds & migratory \\

    Ifrita kowaldi & Orthonychidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Pachycephala philippinensis & Pachycephalidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Paradisaea raggiana & Paradisaeidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Pardalotus punctatus & Pardalotidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Parus major & Paridae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Setophaga coronata & Parulidae & Passeriformes & land birds & migratory \\

    Passer domesticus & Passeridae & Passeriformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Drymodes brunneopygia & Petroicidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Peucedramus taeniatus & Peucedramidae & Passeriformes & land birds & partial migratory \\

    Neodrepanis coruscans & Philepittidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Picathartes gymnocephalus & Picathartidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Pitta sordida & Pittidae & Passeriformes & land birds & migratory \\

    Dyaphorophyia castanea & Platysteiridae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Ploceus nigricollis & Ploceidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Polioptila caerulea & Polioptilidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & migratory \\

    Pomatostomus ruficeps & Pomatostomidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & partial migratory \\

    Promerops cafer & Promeropidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & partial migratory \\

    Prunella himalayana & Prunellidae & Passeriformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

    Ptilonorhynchus violaceus & Ptilonorhynchidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Nicator chloris & Pycnonotidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Regulus satrapa & Regulidae & Passeriformes & land birds & migratory \\

    Anthoscopus minutus & Remizidae & Passeriformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Rhabdornis inornatus & Rhabdornithidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Scytalopus superciliaris & Rhinocryptidae & Passeriformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Rhipidura dahli & Rhipiduridae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Sapayoa aenigma & Sapayoaidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Sitta europaea & Sittidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Buphagus erythrorhynchus & Sturnidae & Passeriformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Oxylabes madagascariensis & Sylviidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Rhegmatorhina hoffmannsi & Thamnophilidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Rhodinocichla rosea & Thraupidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Sinosuthora webbiana & Timaliidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Thryothorus ludovicianus & Troglodytidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Catharus fuscescens & Turdidae & Passeriformes & land birds & migratory \\

    Tyrannus savana & Tyrannidae & Passeriformes & water birds & migratory \\

    Urocynchramus pylzowi & Urocynchramidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Vidua chalybeata & Viduidae & Passeriformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Vidua macroura & Viduidae & Passeriformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Vireo altiloquus & Vireonidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Zosterops lateralis & Zosteropidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Cochlearius cochlearius & Ardeidae & Pelecaniformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Balaeniceps rex & Balaenicipitidae & Pelecaniformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Pelecanus crispus & Pelecanidae & Pelecaniformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

    Scopus umbretta & Scopidae & Pelecaniformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

    Mesembrinibis cayennensis & Threskiornithidae & Pelecaniformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Phaethon lepturus & Phaethontidae & Phaethontiformes & water birds & migratory \\

    Phoenicopterus ruber & Phoenicopteridae & Phoenicopteriformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Bucco capensis & Bucconidae & Piciformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Galbula dea & Galbulidae & Piciformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Indicator maculatus & Indicatoridae & Piciformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Picoides pubescens & Picidae & Piciformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Ramphastos sulfuratus & Ramphastidae & Piciformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Podiceps cristatus & Podicipedidae & Podicipediformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Thalassarche chlororhynchos & Diomedeidae & Procellariiformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

    Hydrobates tethys & Hydrobatidae & Procellariiformes & water birds & migratory \\

    Pelecanoides urinatrix & Pelecanoididae & Procellariiformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

    Fulmarus glacialis & Procellariidae & Procellariiformes & water birds & migratory \\

    Amazona guildingii & Psittacidae & Psittaciformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Syrrhaptes paradoxus & Pteroclididae & Pterocliformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

    Pygoscelis adeliae & Spheniscidae & Sphenisciformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

    Glaucidium brasilianum & Strigidae & Strigiformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Tyto alba & Tytonidae & Strigiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Apteryx rowi & Apterygidae & Struthioniformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Casuarius casuarius & Casuariidae & Struthioniformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Dromaius novaehollandiae & Dromaiidae & Struthioniformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Rhea americana & Rheidae & Struthioniformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Struthio camelus & Struthionidae & Struthioniformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Anhinga anhinga & Anhingidae & Suliformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Phalacrocorax brasilianus & Phalacrocoracidae & Suliformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Sula dactylatra & Sulidae & Suliformes & water birds & partial migratory \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}%
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a minimal working example instead of a code snippet.

Comment: How often did you compile the document? For `longtable` to work correctly you need to compile your document multiple times, according to documentation, usually this will be 3 or 4 runs to get it somewhat reliably right.

Comment: My document automatically compiles 5 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is described at page 7 in the [longtable manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf). Add the commands:

```
\setlength\LTleft{-2.5cm}
\setlength\LTright{\fill}
```

before the `longtable`, and it will be moved 2.5 cm into the left margin, which, for your example, was enough to fit it approximately in the centre. If  you need higher precision, you have to calculate the width of your tabular to see how much you need to move it to the left. Also, I suggest you add to the document preamble:

```
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
```

to have more distance between the `hline` and the table header (unnecessary if you use [booktabs](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable)).

If you prefer a centred first column, you have two options: If you have cells with more than one line, you need a `p`-column, and to centre its content, you redirect a `\centering` command into the column, using the preamble:

```
\begin{longtable}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{6cm}| *{4}{c|} }
```

(I reduced the number og columns to 5). If you only have one line cells (as in your example), you may use the new fixed width `\w`-column:

```
\begin{longtable}{|wc{6cm}| *{4}{c|} }
```

You need an updated version of [array](https://ctan.org/pkg/array) to use `w`-columns.

In my opinion, your table is cramped and not very unreadable. I suggest that you use a combination of [booktabs](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) rules and white space between each fifth row to increase readability. See example 2.):

**Example 1 – \hline and vertical lines**

[image]

**Example 2 – booktabs, horizontal rules and added space**

[image]

**Code for example 1**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable, array}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.9pt}     
\small\sffamily\centering 

\setlength\LTleft{-2.5cm}
\setlength\LTright{\fill}

%\begin{longtable}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{6cm} | *{4}{c|} }
\begin{longtable}{|wc{6cm}| *{4}{c|}}
%% Alternative ways to centre first column, comment and uncomment the one you prefer

\caption{Species' description, habitats and migration}\\
\multicolumn{5}{c}{}\\

\endfirsthead

\hline
    Species & Family & Order & Habitat & Migration \\ 
    \hline
Pandion haliaetus & Accipitridae & Accipitriformes & water birds & migratory \\

    Anas platyrhynchos & Anatidae & Anseriformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

    Chauna torquata & Anhimidae & Anseriformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Anseranas semipalmata & Anseranatidae & Anseriformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

    Buceros rhinoceros & Bucerotidae & Bucerotiformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Bucorvus abyssinicus & Bucorvidae & Bucerotiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Rhinopomastus cyanomelas & Phoeniculidae & Bucerotiformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Upupa epops & Upupidae & Bucerotiformes & water birds & migratory \\

    Aegotheles bennettii & Aegothelidae & Caprimulgiformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Chaetura pelagica & Apodidae & Caprimulgiformes & land birds & migratory \\

    Chordeiles acutipennis & Caprimulgidae & Caprimulgiformes & intermidate regions & partial migratory \\

    Calypte anna & Trochilidae & Caprimulgiformes & intermidate regions & partial migratory \\

    Chunga burmeisteri & Cariamidae & Cariamiformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Gymnogyps californianus & Cathartidae & Cathartiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Uria aalge & Alcidae & Charadriiformes & water birds & migratory \\

    Burhinus bistriatus & Burhinidae & Charadriiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Charadrius vociferus & Charadriidae & Charadriiformes & water birds & migratory \\

    Chionis minor & Chionidae & Charadriiformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

    Dromas ardeola & Dromadidae & Charadriiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Rhinoptilus africanus & Glareolidae & Charadriiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Ibidorhyncha struthersii & Ibidorhynchidae & Charadriiformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

    Jacana jacana & Jacanidae & Charadriiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Chroicocephalus maculipennis & Laridae & Charadriiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Pedionomus torquatus & Pedionomidae & Charadriiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Himantopus himantopus & Recurvirostridae & Charadriiformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

    Rostratula benghalensis & Rostratulidae & Charadriiformes & land birds & partial migratory \\

    Limosa lapponica & Scolopacidae & Charadriiformes & water birds & migratory \\

    Stercorarius parasiticus & Stercorariidae & Charadriiformes & water birds & migratory \\

    Thinocorus orbignyianus & Thinocoridae & Charadriiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Turnix velox & Turnicidae & Charadriiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Ciconia maguari & Ciconiidae & Ciconiiformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

    Colius striatus & Coliidae & Coliiformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Columbina picui & Columbidae & Columbiformes & water birds & migratory \\

    Halcyon senegalensis & Alcedinidae & Coraciiformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Brachypteracias leptosomus & Brachypteraciidae & Coraciiformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Eurystomus gularis & Coraciidae & Coraciiformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Merops nubicus & Meropidae & Coraciiformes & intermidate regions & partial migratory \\

    Baryphthengus martii & Momotidae & Coraciiformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Todus mexicanus & Todidae & Coraciiformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Centropus bengalensis & Cuculidae & Cuculiformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Eurypyga helias & Eurypygidae & Eurypygiformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Rhynochetos jubatus & Rhynochetidae & Eurypygiformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Falco peregrinus & Falconidae & Falconiformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

    Penelope pileata & Cracidae & Galliformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Alectura lathami & Megapodiidae & Galliformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Numida meleagris & Numididae & Galliformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Odontophorus gujanensis & Odontophoridae & Galliformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Tympanuchus cupido & Phasianidae & Galliformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Gavia stellata & Gaviidae & Gaviiformes & water birds & migratory \\

    Aramus guarauna & Aramidae & Gruiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Grus americana & Gruidae & Gruiformes & water birds & migratory \\

    Heliornis fulica & Heliornithidae & Gruiformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Atlantisia rogersi & Rallidae & Gruiformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Leptosomus discolor & Leptosomidae & Leptosomiformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Mesitornis unicolor & Mesitornithidae & Mesitornithiformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Corythaixoides concolor & Musophagidae & Musophagiformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Opisthocomus hoazin & Opisthocomidae & Opisthocomiformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Lophotis ruficrista & Otididae & Otidiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Acanthisitta chloris & Acanthisittidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Mohoua ochrocephala & Acanthizidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Aegithalos caudatus & Aegithalidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Alaudala cheleensis & Alaudidae & Passeriformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

    Artamus cinereus & Artamidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Atrichornis clamosus & Atrichornithidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Bombycilla garrulus & Bombycillidae & Passeriformes & land birds & migratory \\

    Callaeas wilsoni & Callaeatidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Edolisoma coerulescens & Campephagidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Cardinalis cardinalis & Cardinalidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Certhia familiaris & Certhiidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Chloropsis hardwickii & Chloropseidae & Passeriformes & land birds & migratory \\

    Cinclus mexicanus & Cinclidae & Passeriformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Cisticola juncidis & Cisticolidae & Passeriformes & water birds & migratory \\

    Climacteris rufus & Climacteridae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Cnemophilus loriae & Cnemophilidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Struthidea cinerea & Corcoracidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Corvus corone & Corvidae & Passeriformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Oxyruncus cristatus & Cotingidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Gymnorhina tibicen & Cracticidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Machaerirhynchus nigripectus & Machaerirhynchidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Dryoscopus gambensis & Malaconotidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Malurus elegans & Maluridae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Melanocharis versteri & Melanocharitidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Notiomystis cincta & Meliphagidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Menura novaehollandiae & Menuridae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Toxostoma redivivum & Mimidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Myiagra hebetior & Monarchidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Motacilla alba & Motacillidae & Passeriformes & water birds & migratory \\

    Erithacus rubecula & Muscicapidae & Passeriformes & land birds & migratory \\

    Leptocoma aspasia & Nectariniidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Daphoenositta chrysoptera & Neosittidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Oriolus oriolus & Oriolidae & Passeriformes & land birds & migratory \\

    Ifrita kowaldi & Orthonychidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Pachycephala philippinensis & Pachycephalidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Paradisaea raggiana & Paradisaeidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Pardalotus punctatus & Pardalotidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Parus major & Paridae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Setophaga coronata & Parulidae & Passeriformes & land birds & migratory \\

    Passer domesticus & Passeridae & Passeriformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Drymodes brunneopygia & Petroicidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Peucedramus taeniatus & Peucedramidae & Passeriformes & land birds & partial migratory \\

    Neodrepanis coruscans & Philepittidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Picathartes gymnocephalus & Picathartidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Pitta sordida & Pittidae & Passeriformes & land birds & migratory \\

    Dyaphorophyia castanea & Platysteiridae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Ploceus nigricollis & Ploceidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Polioptila caerulea & Polioptilidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & migratory \\

    Pomatostomus ruficeps & Pomatostomidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & partial migratory \\

    Promerops cafer & Promeropidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & partial migratory \\

    Prunella himalayana & Prunellidae & Passeriformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

    Ptilonorhynchus violaceus & Ptilonorhynchidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Nicator chloris & Pycnonotidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Regulus satrapa & Regulidae & Passeriformes & land birds & migratory \\

    Anthoscopus minutus & Remizidae & Passeriformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Rhabdornis inornatus & Rhabdornithidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Scytalopus superciliaris & Rhinocryptidae & Passeriformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Rhipidura dahli & Rhipiduridae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Sapayoa aenigma & Sapayoaidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Sitta europaea & Sittidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Buphagus erythrorhynchus & Sturnidae & Passeriformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Oxylabes madagascariensis & Sylviidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Rhegmatorhina hoffmannsi & Thamnophilidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Rhodinocichla rosea & Thraupidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Sinosuthora webbiana & Timaliidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Thryothorus ludovicianus & Troglodytidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Catharus fuscescens & Turdidae & Passeriformes & land birds & migratory \\

    Tyrannus savana & Tyrannidae & Passeriformes & water birds & migratory \\

    Urocynchramus pylzowi & Urocynchramidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Vidua chalybeata & Viduidae & Passeriformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Vidua macroura & Viduidae & Passeriformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Vireo altiloquus & Vireonidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Zosterops lateralis & Zosteropidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Cochlearius cochlearius & Ardeidae & Pelecaniformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Balaeniceps rex & Balaenicipitidae & Pelecaniformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Pelecanus crispus & Pelecanidae & Pelecaniformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

    Scopus umbretta & Scopidae & Pelecaniformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

    Mesembrinibis cayennensis & Threskiornithidae & Pelecaniformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Phaethon lepturus & Phaethontidae & Phaethontiformes & water birds & migratory \\

    Phoenicopterus ruber & Phoenicopteridae & Phoenicopteriformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Bucco capensis & Bucconidae & Piciformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Galbula dea & Galbulidae & Piciformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Indicator maculatus & Indicatoridae & Piciformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Picoides pubescens & Picidae & Piciformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Ramphastos sulfuratus & Ramphastidae & Piciformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Podiceps cristatus & Podicipedidae & Podicipediformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Thalassarche chlororhynchos & Diomedeidae & Procellariiformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

    Hydrobates tethys & Hydrobatidae & Procellariiformes & water birds & migratory \\

    Pelecanoides urinatrix & Pelecanoididae & Procellariiformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

    Fulmarus glacialis & Procellariidae & Procellariiformes & water birds & migratory \\

    Amazona guildingii & Psittacidae & Psittaciformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Syrrhaptes paradoxus & Pteroclididae & Pterocliformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

    Pygoscelis adeliae & Spheniscidae & Sphenisciformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

    Glaucidium brasilianum & Strigidae & Strigiformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

    Tyto alba & Tytonidae & Strigiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Apteryx rowi & Apterygidae & Struthioniformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Casuarius casuarius & Casuariidae & Struthioniformes & land birds & non migratory \\

    Dromaius novaehollandiae & Dromaiidae & Struthioniformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Rhea americana & Rheidae & Struthioniformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Struthio camelus & Struthionidae & Struthioniformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Anhinga anhinga & Anhingidae & Suliformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Phalacrocorax brasilianus & Phalacrocoracidae & Suliformes & water birds & non migratory \\

    Sula dactylatra & Sulidae & Suliformes & water birds & partial migratory \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

**Code for example 2**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable, array, booktabs}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}

\begin{document}


\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt} 
\small\sffamily
\setlength\LTleft{-2.75cm}
\setlength\LTright{\fill}
%\begin{longtable}{@{}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{6cm} *{4}{c}@{}}
\begin{longtable}{@{}wc{6cm} *{4}{c}@{}}

\caption{Species' description, habitats and migration}\\

\toprule
\bfseries Species & \bfseries Family & \bfseries Order & \bfseries Habitat & \bfseries Migration \\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\toprule
\bfseries Species & \bfseries Family & \bfseries Order & \bfseries Habitat & \bfseries Migration \\ 
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

Pandion haliaetus & Accipitridae & Accipitriformes & water birds & migratory \\

Anas platyrhynchos & Anatidae & Anseriformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

Chauna torquata & Anhimidae & Anseriformes & water birds & non migratory \\

Anseranas semipalmata & Anseranatidae & Anseriformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

Buceros rhinoceros & Bucerotidae & Bucerotiformes & land birds & non migratory \\
\addlinespace[1.5ex]
Bucorvus abyssinicus & Bucorvidae & Bucerotiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

Rhinopomastus cyanomelas & Phoeniculidae & Bucerotiformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

Upupa epops & Upupidae & Bucerotiformes & water birds & migratory \\

Aegotheles bennettii & Aegothelidae & Caprimulgiformes & land birds & non migratory \\

Chaetura pelagica & Apodidae & Caprimulgiformes & land birds & migratory \\
\addlinespace[1.5ex]
Chordeiles acutipennis & Caprimulgidae & Caprimulgiformes & intermidate regions & partial migratory \\

Hemiprocne comata & Hemiprocnidae & Caprimulgiformes & land birds & non migratory \\

Nyctibius grandis & Nyctibiidae & Caprimulgiformes & land birds & non migratory \\

Podargus strigoides & Podargidae & Caprimulgiformes & land birds & non migratory \\

Calypte anna & Trochilidae & Caprimulgiformes & intermidate regions & partial migratory \\
\addlinespace[1.5ex]
Chunga burmeisteri & Cariamidae & Cariamiformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

Gymnogyps californianus & Cathartidae & Cathartiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

Uria aalge & Alcidae & Charadriiformes & water birds & migratory \\

Burhinus bistriatus & Burhinidae & Charadriiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

Charadrius vociferus & Charadriidae & Charadriiformes & water birds & migratory \\
\addlinespace[1.5ex]
Chionis minor & Chionidae & Charadriiformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

Dromas ardeola & Dromadidae & Charadriiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

Rhinoptilus africanus & Glareolidae & Charadriiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

Ibidorhyncha struthersii & Ibidorhynchidae & Charadriiformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

Jacana jacana & Jacanidae & Charadriiformes & water birds & non migratory \\
\addlinespace[1.5ex]
Chroicocephalus maculipennis & Laridae & Charadriiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

Pedionomus torquatus & Pedionomidae & Charadriiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

Himantopus himantopus & Recurvirostridae & Charadriiformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

Rostratula benghalensis & Rostratulidae & Charadriiformes & land birds & partial migratory \\

Limosa lapponica & Scolopacidae & Charadriiformes & water birds & migratory \\
\addlinespace[1.5ex]
Stercorarius parasiticus & Stercorariidae & Charadriiformes & water birds & migratory \\

Thinocorus orbignyianus & Thinocoridae & Charadriiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

Turnix velox & Turnicidae & Charadriiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

Ciconia maguari & Ciconiidae & Ciconiiformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

Colius striatus & Coliidae & Coliiformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\
\addlinespace[1.5ex]
Columbina picui & Columbidae & Columbiformes & water birds & migratory \\

Halcyon senegalensis & Alcedinidae & Coraciiformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

Brachypteracias leptosomus & Brachypteraciidae & Coraciiformes & land birds & non migratory \\

Eurystomus gularis & Coraciidae & Coraciiformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

Merops nubicus & Meropidae & Coraciiformes & intermidate regions & partial migratory \\
\addlinespace[1.5ex]
Baryphthengus martii & Momotidae & Coraciiformes & land birds & non migratory \\

Todus mexicanus & Todidae & Coraciiformes & land birds & non migratory \\

Centropus bengalensis & Cuculidae & Cuculiformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

Eurypyga helias & Eurypygidae & Eurypygiformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

Rhynochetos jubatus & Rhynochetidae & Eurypygiformes & land birds & non migratory \\
\addlinespace[1.5ex]
Falco peregrinus & Falconidae & Falconiformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

Penelope pileata & Cracidae & Galliformes & land birds & non migratory \\

Alectura lathami & Megapodiidae & Galliformes & land birds & non migratory \\

Numida meleagris & Numididae & Galliformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

Odontophorus gujanensis & Odontophoridae & Galliformes & land birds & non migratory \\
\addlinespace[1.5ex]
Tympanuchus cupido & Phasianidae & Galliformes & water birds & non migratory \\

Gavia stellata & Gaviidae & Gaviiformes & water birds & migratory \\

Aramus guarauna & Aramidae & Gruiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

Grus americana & Gruidae & Gruiformes & water birds & migratory \\

Heliornis fulica & Heliornithidae & Gruiformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\
\addlinespace[1.5ex]
Atlantisia rogersi & Rallidae & Gruiformes & land birds & non migratory \\

Leptosomus discolor & Leptosomidae & Leptosomiformes & land birds & non migratory \\

Mesitornis unicolor & Mesitornithidae & Mesitornithiformes & land birds & non migratory \\

Corythaixoides concolor & Musophagidae & Musophagiformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

Opisthocomus hoazin & Opisthocomidae & Opisthocomiformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\
\addlinespace[1.5ex]
Lophotis ruficrista & Otididae & Otidiformes & water birds & non migratory \\

Acanthisitta chloris & Acanthisittidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

Mohoua ochrocephala & Acanthizidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

Aegithalos caudatus & Aegithalidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

Alaudala cheleensis & Alaudidae & Passeriformes & water birds & partial migratory \\
\addlinespace[1.5ex]
Artamus cinereus & Artamidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

Atrichornis clamosus & Atrichornithidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

Bombycilla garrulus & Bombycillidae & Passeriformes & land birds & migratory \\

Callaeas wilsoni & Callaeatidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

Edolisoma coerulescens & Campephagidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\
\addlinespace[1.5ex]
Cardinalis cardinalis & Cardinalidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

Certhia familiaris & Certhiidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

Chloropsis hardwickii & Chloropseidae & Passeriformes & land birds & migratory \\

Cinclus mexicanus & Cinclidae & Passeriformes & water birds & non migratory \\

Cisticola juncidis & Cisticolidae & Passeriformes & water birds & migratory \\
\addlinespace[1.5ex]
Climacteris rufus & Climacteridae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

Cnemophilus loriae & Cnemophilidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

Struthidea cinerea & Corcoracidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

Corvus corone & Corvidae & Passeriformes & water birds & non migratory \\

Oxyruncus cristatus & Cotingidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\
\addlinespace[1.5ex]
Oriolus oriolus & Oriolidae & Passeriformes & land birds & migratory \\

Ifrita kowaldi & Orthonychidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

Pachycephala philippinensis & Pachycephalidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

Paradisaea raggiana & Paradisaeidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

Pardalotus punctatus & Pardalotidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\
\addlinespace[1.5ex]
Parus major & Paridae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

Setophaga coronata & Parulidae & Passeriformes & land birds & migratory \\

Passer domesticus & Passeridae & Passeriformes & water birds & non migratory \\

Drymodes brunneopygia & Petroicidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\

Peucedramus taeniatus & Peucedramidae & Passeriformes & land birds & partial migratory \\
\addlinespace[1.5ex]
Neodrepanis coruscans & Philepittidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

Picathartes gymnocephalus & Picathartidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

Pitta sordida & Pittidae & Passeriformes & land birds & migratory \\

Dyaphorophyia castanea & Platysteiridae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

Ploceus nigricollis & Ploceidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & non migratory \\
\addlinespace[1.5ex]
Polioptila caerulea & Polioptilidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & migratory \\

Pomatostomus ruficeps & Pomatostomidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & partial migratory \\

Promerops cafer & Promeropidae & Passeriformes & intermidate regions & partial migratory \\

Prunella himalayana & Prunellidae & Passeriformes & water birds & partial migratory \\

Ptilonorhynchus violaceus & Ptilonorhynchidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\
\addlinespace[1.5ex]
Nicator chloris & Pycnonotidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

Regulus satrapa & Regulidae & Passeriformes & land birds & migratory \\

Anthoscopus minutus & Remizidae & Passeriformes & water birds & non migratory \\

Rhabdornis inornatus & Rhabdornithidae & Passeriformes & land birds & non migratory \\

Scytalopus superciliaris & Rhinocryptidae & Passeriformes & water birds & non migratory \\

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It worked really well! But is there some way to make the first column be centered as well?

Comment: @RaquelCardoso See updated answer (in 1 minute)

Comment: @RaquelCardoso I had t shorten your example, because my answer was more than 30000 characters

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In normal circumstances `\longtable` is centered in the text area, however
your table is much wider than `\textwidth`. Consequently it spill out of right border of text area and even a page.

If you increase text width, for example with use of the `geometry` package, and reduce font size for example to `\footnotesize`, table will be centered in text area:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}  % <---
\usepackage{array, longtable}

%\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\footnotesize\sffamily   % <---
    \begin{longtable}{|*{5}{c|}}
    \caption{Species' description, habitats and migration}\\
    \hline
Species 
    & Family            & Order             & Habitat               & Migration \\
    \hline
\endfirsthead
    \caption[]{Species' description, habitats and migration (cont.)}\\
    \hline
Species
    & Family            & Order             & Habitat               & Migration \\
    \hline
\endhead
    \hline
    \multicolumn{5}{r}{\textit{Continue on the next page}}
\endfoot
    \hline
\endlastfoot
% table body
Pandion haliaetus 
    & Accipitridae      & Accipitriformes   & water birds           & migratory \\
Anas platyrhynchos 
    & Anatidae          & Anseriformes      & water birds           & partial migratory \\
Chauna torquata 
    & Anhimidae         & Anseriformes      & water birds           & non migratory \\
Anseranas semipalmata 
    & Anseranatidae     & Anseriformes      & water birds           & partial migratory \\
Buceros rhinoceros 
    & Bucerotidae       & Bucerotiformes    & land birds            & non migratory \\
Bucorvus abyssinicus 
        & Bucorvidae    & Bucerotiformes    & water birds           & non migratory \\
Rhinopomastus cyanomelas 
    & Phoeniculidae     & Bucerotiformes    & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Upupa epops 
    & Upupidae          & Bucerotiformes    & water birds           & migratory \\
Aegotheles bennettii 
    & Aegothelidae      & Caprimulgiformes  & land birds            & non migratory \\
Chaetura pelagica 
    & Apodidae          & Caprimulgiformes  & land birds            & migratory \\
Chordeiles acutipennis
    & Caprimulgidae     & Caprimulgiformes  & intermidate regions   & partial migratory \\
Hemiprocne comata 
    & Hemiprocnidae     & Caprimulgiformes  & land birds            & non migratory \\
Nyctibius grandis 
    & Nyctibiidae       & Caprimulgiformes  & land birds            & non migratory \\
Podargus strigoides 
    & Podargidae        & Caprimulgiformes  & land birds            & non migratory \\
Calypte anna 
    & Trochilidae       & Caprimulgiformes  & intermidate regions   & partial migratory \\
Chunga burmeisteri 
    & Cariamidae        & Cariamiformes     & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Gymnogyps californianus 
    & Cathartidae       & Cathartiformes    & water birds           & non migratory \\
Uria aalge 
    & Alcidae           & Charadriiformes   & water birds           & migratory \\
Burhinus bistriatus 
    & Burhinidae        & Charadriiformes   & water birds           & non migratory \\
Charadrius vociferus 
    & Charadriidae      & Charadriiformes   & water birds           & migratory \\
Chionis minor 
    & Chionidae         & Charadriiformes   & water birds           & partial migratory \\
Dromas ardeola 
    & Dromadidae        & Charadriiformes   & water birds           & non migratory \\
Rhinoptilus africanus 
    & Glareolidae       & Charadriiformes   & water birds           & non migratory \\
Ibidorhyncha struthersii 
    & Ibidorhynchidae   & Charadriiformes   & water birds           & partial migratory \\
Jacana jacana 
    & Jacanidae         & Charadriiformes   & water birds           & non migratory \\
Chroicocephalus maculipennis 
    & Laridae           & Charadriiformes   & water birds           & non migratory \\
Pedionomus torquatus 
    & Pedionomidae      & Charadriiformes   & water birds           & non migratory \\
Himantopus himantopus 
    & Recurvirostridae  & Charadriiformes   & water birds           & partial migratory \\
Rostratula benghalensis 
    & Rostratulidae     & Charadriiformes   & land birds            & partial migratory \\
Limosa lapponica 
    & Scolopacidae      & Charadriiformes   & water birds           & migratory \\
Stercorarius parasiticus
    & Stercorariidae    & Charadriiformes   & water birds           & migratory \\
Thinocorus orbignyianus 
    & Thinocoridae      & Charadriiformes   & water birds           & non migratory \\
Turnix velox 
    & Turnicidae        & Charadriiformes   & water birds           & non migratory \\
Ciconia maguari 
    & Ciconiidae        & Ciconiiformes     & water birds           & partial migratory \\
Colius striatus 
    & Coliidae          & Coliiformes       & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Columbina picui 
    & Columbidae        & Columbiformes     & water birds           & migratory \\
Halcyon senegalensis 
    & Alcedinidae       & Coraciiformes     & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Brachypteracias leptosomus 
    & Brachypteraciidae & Coraciiformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Eurystomus gularis 
    & Coraciidae        & Coraciiformes     & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Merops nubicus 
    & Meropidae         & Coraciiformes     & intermidate regions   & partial migratory \\
Baryphthengus martii 
    & Momotidae         & Coraciiformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Todus mexicanus 
    & Todidae           & Coraciiformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Centropus bengalensis 
    & Cuculidae         & Cuculiformes      & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Eurypyga helias
    & Eurypygidae       & Eurypygiformes    & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Rhynochetos jubatus
    & Rhynochetidae     & Eurypygiformes    & land birds            & non migratory \\
Falco peregrinus 
    & Falconidae        & Falconiformes     & water birds           & partial migratory \\
Penelope pileata 
    & Cracidae          & Galliformes       & land birds            & non migratory \\
Alectura lathami 
    & Megapodiidae      & Galliformes       & land birds            & non migratory \\
Numida meleagris 
    & Numididae         & Galliformes       & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Odontophorus gujanensis 
    & Odontophoridae    & Galliformes       & land birds            & non migratory \\
Tympanuchus cupido 
    & Phasianidae       & Galliformes       & water birds           & non migratory \\
Gavia stellata 
    & Gaviidae          & Gaviiformes       & water birds           & migratory \\
Aramus guarauna 
    & Aramidae          & Gruiformes        & water birds           & non migratory \\
Grus americana 
    & Gruidae           & Gruiformes        & water birds           & migratory \\
Heliornis fulica 
    & Heliornithidae    & Gruiformes        & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Atlantisia rogersi 
    & Rallidae          & Gruiformes        & land birds            & non migratory \\
Leptosomus discolor 
    & Leptosomidae      & Leptosomiformes   & land birds            & non migratory \\
Mesitornis unicolor 
    & Mesitornithidae   & Mesitornithiformes& land birds            & non migratory \\
Corythaixoides concolor 
    & Musophagidae      & Musophagiformes   & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Opisthocomus hoazin 
    & Opisthocomidae    & Opisthocomiformes & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Lophotis ruficrista 
    & Otididae          & Otidiformes       & water birds           & non migratory \\
Acanthisitta chloris 
    & Acanthisittidae   & Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Mohoua ochrocephala 
    & Acanthizidae      & Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Aegithalos caudatus 
    & Aegithalidae      & Passeriformes     & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Alaudala cheleensis 
    & Alaudidae         & Passeriformes     & water birds           & partial migratory \\
Artamus cinereus 
    & Artamidae         & Passeriformes     & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Atrichornis clamosus 
    & Atrichornithidae  & Passeriformes     & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Bombycilla garrulus 
    & Bombycillidae     & Passeriformes     & land birds            & migratory \\
Callaeas wilsoni 
    & Callaeatidae      & Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Edolisoma coerulescens 
    & Campephagidae     & Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Cardinalis cardinalis
    & Cardinalidae      & Passeriformes     & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Certhia familiaris 
    & Certhiidae        & Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Chloropsis hardwickii 
    & Chloropseidae     & Passeriformes     & land birds            & migratory \\
Cinclus mexicanus 
    & Cinclidae         & Passeriformes     & water birds           & non migratory \\
Cisticola juncidis 
    & Cisticolidae      & Passeriformes     & water birds           & migratory \\
Climacteris rufus 
    & Climacteridae     & Passeriformes     & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Cnemophilus loriae 
    & Cnemophilidae     & Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Struthidea cinerea 
    & Corcoracidae      & Passeriformes     & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Corvus corone 
    & Corvidae          & Passeriformes     & water birds           & non migratory \\
Oxyruncus cristatus 
    & Cotingidae        & Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Gymnorhina tibicen 
    & Cracticidae       & Passeriformes     & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Dasyornis broadbenti 
    & Dasyornithidae    & Passeriformes     & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Campylorhamphus procurvoides 
    & Dendrocolaptidae  & Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Dicaeum eximium 
    & Dicaeidae         & Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Dicrurus megarhynchus 
    & Dicruridae        & Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Dulus dominicus 
    & Dulidae           & Passeriformes     & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Sporophila hypoxantha 
    & Emberizidae       & Passeriformes     & water birds           & partial migratory \\
Lonchura striata 
    & Estrildidae       & Passeriformes     & water birds           & non migratory \\
Ptilorrhoa leucosticta 
    & Eupetidae         & Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Serilophus lunatus 
    & Eurylaimidae      & Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Eulacestoma nigropectus 
    & Falcunculidae     & Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Formicarius rufipectus 
    & Formicariidae     & Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Serinus canaria
    & Fringillidae      & Passeriformes     & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Furnarius figulus 
    Furnariidae         & Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Hirundo rustica 
    & Hirundinidae      & Passeriformes     & water birds           & migratory \\
Molothrus ater 
    & Icteridae         & Passeriformes     & intermidate regions   & migratory \\
Irena cyanogastra 
    & Irenidae          & Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Lanius ludovicianus 
    & Laniidae          & Passeriformes     & water birds           & migratory \\
Machaerirhynchus nigripectus 
    & Machaerirhynchidae& Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Dryoscopus gambensis 
    & Malaconotidae     & Passeriformes     & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Malurus elegans 
    & Maluridae         & Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Melanocharis versteri 
    & Melanocharitidae  & Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Notiomystis cincta 
    & Meliphagidae      & Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Menura novaehollandiae 
    & Menuridae         & Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Toxostoma redivivum 
    & Mimidae           & Passeriformes     & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Myiagra hebetior 
    & Monarchidae       & Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Motacilla alba 
    & Motacillidae      & Passeriformes     & water birds           & migratory \\
Erithacus rubecula 
    & Muscicapidae      & Passeriformes     & land birds            & migratory \\
Leptocoma aspasia 
    & Nectariniidae     & Passeriformes     & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Daphoenositta chrysoptera 
    & Neosittidae       & Passeriformes     & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Oriolus oriolus 
    & Oriolidae         & Passeriformes     & land birds            & migratory \\
Ifrita kowaldi 
    & Orthonychidae     & Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Pachycephala philippinensis 
    & Pachycephalidae   & Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Paradisaea raggiana 
    & Paradisaeidae     & Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Pardalotus punctatus 
    & Pardalotidae      & Passeriformes     & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Parus major 
    & Paridae           & Passeriformes     & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Setophaga coronata 
    & Parulidae         & Passeriformes     & land birds            & migratory \\
Passer domesticus 
    & Passeridae        & Passeriformes     & water birds           & non migratory \\
Drymodes brunneopygia 
    & Petroicidae       & Passeriformes     & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Peucedramus taeniatus 
    & Peucedramidae     & Passeriformes     & land birds            & partial migratory\\
Neodrepanis coruscans 
    & Philepittidae     & Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Picathartes gymnocephalus 
    & Picathartidae     & Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Pitta sordida 
    & Pittidae          & Passeriformes     & land birds            & migratory \\
Dyaphorophyia castanea 
    & Platysteiridae    & Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Ploceus nigricollis 
    & Ploceidae         & Passeriformes     & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Polioptila caerulea 
    & Polioptilidae     & Passeriformes     & intermidate regions   & migratory \\
Pomatostomus ruficeps 
    & Pomatostomidae    & Passeriformes     & intermidate regions   & partial migratory \\
Promerops cafer 
    & Promeropidae      & Passeriformes     & intermidate regions   & partial migratory \\
Prunella himalayana 
    & Prunellidae       & Passeriformes     & water birds           & partial migratory \\
Ptilonorhynchus violaceus 
    & Ptilonorhynchidae & Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Nicator chloris 
    & Pycnonotidae      & Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Regulus satrapa 
    & Regulidae         & Passeriformes     & land birds            & migratory \\
Anthoscopus minutus 
    & Remizidae         & Passeriformes     & water birds           & non migratory \\
Rhabdornis inornatus 
    & Rhabdornithidae   & Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Scytalopus superciliaris 
    & Rhinocryptidae    & Passeriformes     & water birds           & non migratory \\
Rhipidura dahli 
    & Rhipiduridae      & Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Sapayoa aenigma 
    & Sapayoaidae       & Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Sitta europaea 
    & Sittidae          & Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Buphagus erythrorhynchus 
    & Sturnidae         & Passeriformes     & water birds           & non migratory \\
Oxylabes madagascariensis 
    & Sylviidae         & Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Rhegmatorhina hoffmannsi 
    & Thamnophilidae    & Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Rhodinocichla rosea 
    & Thraupidae        & Passeriformes     & land birds            & non migratory \\
Sinosuthora webbiana 
    & Timaliidae        & Passeriformes     & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Thryothorus ludovicianus 
    & Troglodytidae     & Passeriformes     & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Catharus fuscescens 
    & Turdidae          & Passeriformes     & land birds            & migratory \\
Tyrannus savana 
    & Tyrannidae        & Passeriformes     & water birds           & migratory \\
Urocynchramus pylzowi 
    & Urocynchramidae   & Passeriformes     & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Vidua chalybeata 
    & Viduidae          & Passeriformes     & water birds           & non migratory \\
Vidua macroura 
    & Viduidae          & Passeriformes     & water birds           & non migratory \\
Vireo altiloquus 
    & Vireonidae        & Passeriformes     & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Zosterops lateralis 
    & Zosteropidae      & Passeriformes     & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Cochlearius cochlearius 
    & Ardeidae          & Pelecaniformes    & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Balaeniceps rex 
    & Balaenicipitidae  & Pelecaniformes    & water birds           & non migratory \\
Pelecanus crispus 
    & Pelecanidae       & Pelecaniformes    & water birds           & partial migratory \\
Scopus umbretta 
    & Scopidae          & Pelecaniformes    & water birds           & partial migratory \\
Mesembrinibis cayennensis 
    & Threskiornithidae & Pelecaniformes    & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Phaethon lepturus 
    & Phaethontidae     & Phaethontiformes  & water birds           & migratory \\
Phoenicopterus ruber 
    & Phoenicopteridae & Phoenicopteriformes& water birds           & non migratory \\
Bucco capensis 
    & Bucconidae        & Piciformes        & land birds            & non migratory \\
Galbula dea 
    & Galbulidae        & Piciformes        & land birds            & non migratory \\
Indicator maculatus 
    & Indicatoridae     & Piciformes        & land birds            & non migratory \\
Picoides pubescens 
    & Picidae           & Piciformes        & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Ramphastos sulfuratus 
    & Ramphastidae      & Piciformes        & land birds            & non migratory \\
Podiceps cristatus 
    & Podicipedidae     & Podicipediformes  & water birds           & non migratory \\
Thalassarche chlororhynchos 
    & Diomedeidae       & Procellariiformes & water birds           & partial migratory \\
Hydrobates tethys 
    & Hydrobatidae      & Procellariiformes & water birds           & migratory \\
Pelecanoides urinatrix 
    & Pelecanoididae    & Procellariiformes & water birds           & partial migratory \\
Fulmarus glacialis 
    & Procellariidae    & Procellariiformes & water birds           & migratory \\
Amazona guildingii 
    & Psittacidae       & Psittaciformes    & land birds            & non migratory \\
Syrrhaptes paradoxus 
    & Pteroclididae     & Pterocliformes    & water birds           & partial migratory \\
Pygoscelis adeliae 
    & Spheniscidae      & Sphenisciformes   & water birds           & partial migratory \\
Glaucidium brasilianum 
    & Strigidae         & Strigiformes      & intermidate regions   & non migratory \\
Tyto alba 
    & Tytonidae         & Strigiformes      & water birds           & non migratory \\
Apteryx rowi 
    & Apterygidae       & Struthioniformes  & land birds            & non migratory \\
Casuarius casuarius 
    & Casuariidae       & Struthioniformes  & land birds            & non migratory \\
Dromaius novaehollandiae 
    & Dromaiidae        & Struthioniformes  & water birds           & non migratory \\
Rhea americana 
    & Rheidae           & Struthioniformes  & water birds           & non migratory \\
Struthio camelus 
    & Struthionidae     & Struthioniformes  & water birds           & non migratory \\
Anhinga anhinga 
    & Anhingidae        & Suliformes        & water birds           & non migratory \\
Phalacrocorax brasilianus 
    & Phalacrocoracidae & Suliformes        & water birds           & non migratory \\
Sula dactylatra 
    & Sulidae           & Suliformes        & water birds           & partial migratory \\
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Personally I more prefer tables without vertical lines which have left aligned cells' contents and use rules from the `booktabs` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\footnotesize\sffamily
    \begin{longtable}{*{5}{l}}
    \caption{Species' description, habitats and migration}\\
    \toprule
Species 
    & Family            & Order             & Habitat               & Migration \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
    \caption[]{Species' description, habitats and migration (cont.)}\\
    \toprule
Species
    & Family            & Order             & Habitat               & Migration \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \multicolumn{5}{r}{\textit{Continue on the next page}}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
% table body is the same as before
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, this table was really good. However, the rest of the document needed to have equal margins so I used: 
" %MARGIN SETUP
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
a4paper,
left=2.5cm,
right=2.5cm,
bottom=2.5cm,
headheight=0.5cm
}
\setlength\footskip{30pt} %space between page number and end of page"

And this caused the table to be misconfigured. Is there some way to keep the margins on the rest of the document but use the table margins here suggested? maybe with geometry? But I don´t know how.

Thank you

Comment: And what is the problem? You have narrower margins than I set in my MWE, so table will nicely fit in center of text area with your page layout.  For test just add your `\geometry{ a4paper, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, headheight=0.5cm }` after `\usepackage{geometry}` and see result (after two compilation).

Comment: The problem is that, instead of the table fitting nicely as before, it moved to the left, with the lines even touching the extremities of the page. Maybe \newgeometry would solve it?

Comment: I changed \setlength\LTleft{} from 2.75cm to 2cm and now fits perfectly :)

Comment: @RaquelCardoso, my MWE doesn't contain `\setlength\LTleft{} ` (table is centered without it!) so your comment is irrelevant to my answer and consequently it will not help anyone. By.